# C++ Keyboard / Mouse events

Tags: c++, winapi, events, mouse, keypress

I'm developing a Java application where I have to detect the user's activity / inactivity. Basically this is what I have planned to do:

1 -> The program will have a counter / time-out, and when it reaches x seconds it will change the user status till he / she does something again.

2 -> When user presses any key or moves his / her mouse anywhere the program will reset the counter.

As far as I know I cannot have total control of input devices outside of my Java application due to platform / Security reasons, BUT giving the circunstances I have no choice to develop an external C++ program using the JNI Framework which interacts with the Windows API and give me total control of the events.

Now my question is: How can I know if user moves the mouse / presses keys through the WinAPI, (windows.h)?

I would appretiate any manual / guide you would like to share with me in order to accomplish that..

Thank you.

Comment: Java windows have support for input events.

Comment: Interesting, can you please fill me in?

Comment: What are you using for your GUI?

Comment: I use Swing lib for the GUI, but the point is that Java doesn't register events when the application is unfocused, by the way it's going to be a hidden program without GUI at all, and I need to keep registering the events globally..

Comment: Well that's extremely dumb if you mean it won't even capture mouse movements over your window. And globally, yes, you would probably want a hook. If it's system-wide activity, though, there's a function for that called `GetLastInputInfo` IIRC.

Comment: It's the way that Java works, you're in the window -> You can capture, you're outside -> You can't capture, I know Java / C++ combination it's a totally mess since it breaks up the Java filosofy, but there is a reason of why I am doing this, by the way, could you please explain me how the WinAPI event for both (KB/Mouse) could be handled in C++? Thank's for take your time..

Comment: I gave you two options. There are so many examples of hooks out there and the second is one function call.

Comment: Woah GetLastInputInfo sounds very helpful, I will check it out later, it seems that I'm done with this, Thank you very much! :)